# Preferences with different height

Tags: java, android, preferences, preferenceactivity, preference

I have main.java:

```
public class Main extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.activity);
    PreferenceScreen screen = this.getPreferenceScreen();
    
    Preference preference;
    preference = new Preference(screen.getContext());
    preference.setSummary("Hi");
    screen.addPreference(preference);
    preference = new Preference(screen.getContext());
    preference.setSummary("Hi");
    screen.addPreference(preference);
    preference = new Preference(screen.getContext());
    preference.setSummary("Hi");
    screen.addPreference(preference);
    preference = new Preference(screen.getContext());
    preference.setSummary("Hi");
    screen.addPreference(preference);
    preference = new Preference(screen.getContext());
    preference.setSummary("My long text");
    screen.addPreference(preference);
    preference = new Preference(screen.getContext());
    preference.setSummary("My long text");
    screen.addPreference(preference);
}
```

And my activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When my scroll at the top of the list:

[image]

And when my scroll at the bottom of the list:

[image]

ScrollBar is change during scrolling. When I have all Preferences the same height, then all is well.